# Rabbit ForgivingExceptionHandler An expected connection driver occurred

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-rabbit

Rabbit ForgivingExceptionHandler An expected connection driver occurred, underlying exception id MissedHeartbeatException: Heartbeat missing with heartbeat = 60 seconds, what causing the connection closed whereas rabbit is up and running fine. Connection has been created with Channel.

Comment: Any chances to see a simple project from you to reproduce the problem?

Comment: Not reproducible locally

Comment: You should ask questions about RabbitMQ on the rabbitmq-users Google group - the engineers don't monitor Stack Overflow.